# Creating a mirror image horizontally

Tags: python

I need assistance creating a triangle that reflects to create an M. I figured out how to make a triangle into a diamond vertically, but can't do it horizontally.

```
for f in range(1,9):

for f2 in range(1-f,0,-1):
    print(" ", end='')
for f1 in range(1,f+1):
    print("*", end=' ')
    print()
```

I'm not sure how to keep them on the same axis. Would really appreciate the help.This is the code for the diamond:

```
for f in range(1,21):

for f2 in range(20-f,0,-1):
    print(" ", end='')
for f1 in range(1,f+1):
    print("*", end=' ')
print()
for f in range(1,20):

for f1 in range(1,f+1):
    print("", end=' ')
for f2 in range(20-f,0,-1):
    print("*", end=' ')

print()
```

Comment: please fix your indention

Comment: Your last edit did not fix the indention. All of the for loops are on the same level still.

Comment: I think I fixed it, Hoopdady. There is the code for the diamond, Ivan

Comment: As Hoopdady said, having two for loops one after the other with the same indentation (as is the case in your example) is not valid python syntax. Presumably it's not indented like that when you run it?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear to me.
However, if you are trying to draw on the screen using characters such as "*", i suggest to draw your shapes (triangle, diamond, etc) in memory in a matrix.
Then you can print just the matrix on the screen, or if you want to invert the axis you can just print make the trasposed matrix.
Once you have the matrix in memory you can execute for free many operations.

Of course you need a matrix lib, which for Python is defintely numpy.

Cheers

Charlie

PS: and don' t forget to fix the indentation!